# How can I launch a new Terminal in OSX with a specified profile from the command line?

Tags: macos, terminal.app

I found the same question and a strong answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4404242/147265

I'm looking to launch new terminals from the CLI in a different profile than my default. My current implementation opens a new terminal no problem, but I don't know the option to set the profile.

```
open_term () {                                                 
  osascript -e "tell app \"Terminal\"
     do script \"clear; hello $1 \"
  end tell"
}
open_term world
```

The new terminal will open and greet with "hello world"

I would expect there to be some option for Terminal to specify profile, like `-p "Man Page"`.

Here is the closest I've found to docs, but no profile option or similar: [Terminal.app readme](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_Apple__Terminal_app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export your settings profile from the preferences window, then open the settings file with the `open` command.  For example:

```
bash-3.2$ open "Documents/Man Page.terminal"
```

Comment: Wow! That's fantastic! Is there a way to pass a command while opening?

Comment: I found that I can dig into the props with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150380/mac-os-x-open-terminal-with-specified-windows I'm now looking at how to pass a parameter.

Comment: Just add the parameter to the [start command](http://i.imgur.com/wmknRdi.png).

Comment: Yeah, I can do a hard coded one, but I'm looking to pass parameters. This question looks to be right in line with what I'm looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404242/programmatically-launch-terminal-app-with-a-specified-command-and-custom-colors

Comment: Each time I `open Documents/CLI.terminal`, Terminal creates a new entry in the Terminal profiles list (Terminal settings). When I first run it, I see a new `CLI 1` profile show up. Run again and `CLI 2` profile shows up, then `CLI 3` and so on. How do I prevent this build up?

Answer (score 1):

To run a particular command in the terminal such as a script called yourcommand stored in your bin directory, use 'export settings' from a terminal profile that you like to create a file with extension .terminal, then edit the .terminal file in a text editor and specify

```
    <key>CommandString</key>
    <string>/Users/youruserid/bin/yourcommand</string>  
    <key>RunCommandAsShell</key>
    <true/>
```

Then you can double-click or use the open command to run this and open a new terminal on this command.

Answer (score 0):

@djb: I found the way to prevent opening .terminal files from creating duplicate profiles is to edit the files and remove the `<name>` key, if it is present. i.e.:

```
<key>name</key>
<string>vpn.MacMini2.wan.green</string>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This didn't work for me on macOS Ventura