# How can I run a single Terminal window or tab with zsh in macOS?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, zsh

As many of you know, macOS is switching to `zsh` from `bash`. Before converting, I would like to play with `zsh` a bit.

Is there a way to open a single Terminal window or tab as a `zsh` shell, without having to set `zsh` as my *default* shell?

Can I, say, set up a profile in Terminal preferences with a Startup Run command that'll make windows/tabs opened with that profile run with a `zsh` shell?

*Update:*
I got something like what I want by creating a profile in Terminal preferences, clicking the `Shell` tab, clicking `Run command`, adding the command `exec /bin/zsh`, and clicking `Run inside shell`.

This does open a Terminal window running `zsh` - inside of `bash`. I'm looking, however, for a window opened running `zsh` on its own...

*Clarification:*
I want the shell to run the normal `zsh` startup/shutdown files - *without* having to change my *default* shell yet.

Comment: I don't get your point exactly. Why is `exec zsh` not sufficient to "play" a little bit? `exec` replaces the current shell with _zsh_, it's not run inside _bash_. Maybe you want to use `exec zsh -l` to get a socalled login shell, which sources different files; see _INVOCATION_ in `man zsh`.

Comment: Yes, @mpy, I believe the "login shell" is what I am looking for. When I entered `exec zsh -l`, though, the window just crashed. Based on the `man zsh` page, I tried `exec /bin/zsh -i`("force shell to be interactive"), and the window opened. Now, I just need to test whether that runs the appropriate login and logout files (which is what I'm looking for)...

Answer (score 0):

To launch an instance of the macOS Terminal App with a different shell you can launch a terminal with a different profile.
To do so, you need to export your settings profile from the preferences window, then open the settings file with the `open` command. For example:

```
open Documents/Profile.terminal
```

[Related qestion](https://superuser.com/questions/731133/how-can-i-launch-a-new-terminal-in-osx-with-a-specified-profile-from-the-command)

(As pointed out by @mpy) You can achieve something very similar by running `exec zsh` in bash.

Running `exec zsh` in bash **replaces** current process with zsh shell. You are not running zsh inside bash anymore, *all* the startup files were executed/sourced and *all* the shutdown files will run when the shell exits. This should be the exact experience you get when switching your default shell from bash to zsh.

It's not technically correct that *all* the startup and shutdown files will run when you `exec zsh` or when you launch a new terminal. This is because login and non-login shells have different startup/shutdown files they run/source. Some more information explaining login shells follows.

A login shell is the first process that executes under your user ID. When you launch a new terminal you always get a non-login interactive shell. Login shells are not usually interactive.

For more information about login and non-login shells see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell) from unix stack exchange.